# Rename [sharepoint2013] to [sharepoint-2013] and [sharepoint2003] to [sharepoint-2003]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The usual pattern has been followed for the [sharepoint-2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-2007) and [sharepoint-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-2010) versions.

[sharepoint2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint2003) could be done manually I suppose (28 questions) but there are 2092 [sharepoint2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint2013) questions.